# Trying to round a number to the nearest millions

Tags: google-sheets

I have several hundred rows of revenue data that start from row 1 and goes all the way down the sheet in column A. Something that look like this...

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| $135,345,000 |  |
| $200,000,130 |  |
| $383,430,000 |  |
| $4,750,000,000 |  |

I'm trying to figure out what equation I would use in cell B1 and down the rest of column B if I'm trying to round the revenue data in column A to the nearest $100M? For example, in cell B1, I want it to say just $100,000,000. In cell B2, it should be $200,000,000. For Cell B3, it should be 400,000,000. And finally for cell B4 it should be $4,800,000,000

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to correctly specify the **places** parameter in the [**ROUND(value, [places]) function**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093440?hl=en#null).

In this case, all the patterns you provided contain eight zeros, so the places parameter should be -8:

`=ROUND(A1,-8)`

[image: Example]

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you it worked.